# How to debug $http async call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I would like to see what my response in angularJS `$http` call looks like. But I don't know how to stop execution there? (after successfull response)

I've tried to put break point at that place and execution doesn't stop.
I've even tried to put `debugger` directive there, but it doesn't stop. 
This is happening only with $http calls (async calls), otherwise break point stops execution.

I've marked with comment in code where I would like to stop execution of the program.

Code:

```
 $scope.OpenModal = function (event) {
    $("#myModal").css("display", "block");
    var parent_TD = $(event.currentTarget).parent();
    var cMEST_CDO2 = parent_TD.find("#inputDeliveryID").val();
    var res = null;
    $http({
      method: "POST",
      url: $scope.UrlGetDataFromCAORAM,
      data: { cMEST_CDO2: cMEST_CDO2 }
    }).then(function success(response) {

      /* I would like to stop the program in this point */

      res = response.data;
      $scope.inputCustomerData = res.ACCO_NME + " " + res.ACCO_ADD + " " + res.ACCO_ZIP + " " + res.ACCO_CIT + " " + res.ACCO_VAT;
      $scope.ORAC_DDE = res.ORAC_DDE;
      $scope.ORAC_NUM = res.ORAC_NUM;
      $scope.ArticleName = res.MERC_NME + " (" + MERC_CDO1 + ")";

    }, function failure() {
      alert("Error!");
    })

  }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: do you know what a xhr request is?

Comment: do you know what console.log(response) does?

Comment: Use chrome dev tools and add break point there to see values. Further you can see the response in network tab. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: Can you not just use the browsers debugging tools and put a breakpoint there? Or if you only care about what is being returned just look at the network tab.

Comment: I've tried to put breakpoint there, of course. It doesn't stop there.

Comment: @BadruzZaman - is it possible to break execution at that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to stop execution at that point, use a breakpoint in your browsers "developer tools".

However, if you'd just like to see what the response is to your HTTP call then you can either look in the network tab of your browser's dev tools (assuming your browser has this capability - all popular browsers do) and observe the response to your call.

Lastly, you can just log the response (i.e. with `console.log(response)`) to console in your response callback.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Do you know why execution doesn't stop if I set breakpoint with $http call? Onyl with $http responses, break points are not stopping execution.

Comment: Have you tried setting your breakpoints in the dev tools of your browser? If so, can you send through a screenshot of how you've done it?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your `success function` does gets hit, another approach you can try besides placing a breakpoint is to place the [debugger;](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_debugger.asp) keyword inside your code at the point where you want to start debugging like this:

```
 }).then(function success(response) {

  /* I would like to stop the program in this point */
  debugger;
  ...
```

then make sure that the **developer tools are open** (F12 in your browser) and run the function.